# Simulate iPhone browser on iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile, ios-simulator, iphone

I don't have an iPhone, and I don't have a Mac I could use to run the SDK, but I do have access to an iPad. How can I simulate the iPhone (and iPod Touch) Safari browsing experience on the iPad? I need to be able to replicate the iPhone pixel dimensions at the very least, plus a few things like orientation switching and geolocation that are present in the iPad anyway. It would be nice if it could transmit the iPhone user agent string, but if that's not possible I can work around it.

Comment: Do you have a programming question?

Comment: Do web development and testing not count as programming anymore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

do you already own iphone ? if not, you can use third party browser on ipad. 
i use dolphin browser for iphone. can be installed too on ipad. 
it will have almost same behaviour like safari because apple restrict to only use webkit for any thirdparty web browser.

Comment: @JegBagus. could you provide more details? Do you mean Dolphin could be resized to simulate iphone's dimension?

Comment: This worked great for me, just make sure you choose the iphone app in the app store. Free solution and works well on my ipad 4th gen.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for a solution - there is now an easier way by using a [split screen](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht207582) option to put Safari side by side with another app, and reduce its width to the width of an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably a website like [testiphone.com](http://testiphone.com/), which is a browser-based iPhone simulator. There's no easy way to change the pixel dimensions or user agent string within Mobile Safari, the iPad's default browser, and I'm not aware of any third-party iPad browsers that simulate an iPhone.

Comment: That site just displays web pages in an inline frame with a picture of an iPhone around it. I was hoping for something that would let me test things like orientation changes, pinching and zooming, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one may help you better.
Windows-friendly iOS Web development, profiling and testing.

http://www.electricplum.com/studio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an app called IIRC 'Viewport' but that doesn't seem to be available anymore and I remember it being very limited anyway.

After spending all afternoon trying to create an iframe based testing tool myself (which is futile because of the handling of `vh` and `position: fixed`) I finally found this:

#### "Inspect Browser"

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inspect-browser/id1203594958?mt=8